# Child div with position:relative and top:xx% (android Chrome bug?)

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

Checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p2hpab8q/

In desktop Chrome, the red rectangle (relatively positioned child) is vertically centered in the blue parent (absolutely positioned parent). This is what I would expect.

However, in Android, the red rectangle is aligned to the top (top:50% ignored).

Why the difference? Who is right?

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting note: desktop Safari also behaves differently than Chrome.

Comment: @MihaiT It's a high-res screen: let's say ~1000px high in portrait. In any case, the child should be vertically centered relative to the parent div.

Comment: @andi Woah! Good catch. I am guessing that Safari does this for historic reasons and that Mobile Chrome mimics it to increase compatibility with mobile Safari... I guess neither behavior can be relied upon.

Comment: another note: if you change `bottom:0;` in the parent to `height:100%;`, Safari starts acting like the other browsers.